# Adding horizontal lines to tables created by xtable in R Markdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, xtable

I'm trying to create simple tables with R Markdown (.Rmd), using RStudio. The most customizable and easily applicable way I found is xtable package. 
Even though xtable should produce a table with horizontal lines by default. What I should get would be like [this](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2010/02/making-publicationready-tables-with-xtable.html) (or [these](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf)), but what I get is [this](http://rpubs.com/hbat/6439). I cannot get it with following code:

````
```{r,results='asis'}
library(xtable)
tTable <- xtable(head(mtcars))
print(tTable,type="html",hline.after=c(-1,0))

tTable <- xtable(lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars))
print(tTable,type="html")

```
````

Where am I wrong?

Comment: The examples you show are `LaTeX` tables and you produce a `html` table. Perhaps there is no such thing as horizontal line in html tables produced by `xtable`. Perhaps using `ascii` helps.

Comment: @Henrik I guessed that too. Just want to double check if I'm wrong. I'll look over `ascii`. Thanks for input.

Comment: As @Henrik pointed out, your examples are in PDF files, while you are generating HTML. You can still achieve a similar look, just Google for CSS stylesheets.